# teamcity incremental build MSBuild

Tags: msbuild, teamcity

I have .NET .sln solution that contains about 40 projects, that I build using MSBuild in teamcity ( [image: configuration in attachment] ). And every time it completely rebuilds all projects, that solution contains.
When I build it using my Visual Studio - projects isn't rebuilt completely, just which were changed. And I get message like: 
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 13 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========

I tried solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11888275/how-can-i-make-teamcity-take-advantage-of-msbuilds-incremental-build-support) but it didn't work. Maybe I should do something in addition to that?
How to configure teamcity to skip building projects in sln that up to date.

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to run your build incrementally via msbuild.exe on the build agent machine without TeamCity envolved? If it works and it doesn't work in TeamCity please submit an issue withh all the details to https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/TW.

Comment: Yes, using msbuild.exe manually on my buildagent machine - it takes about 40 seconds, and in log I see for every project: 
"Skipping target "CoreCompile" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files."
But the same using teamcity - it takes 3 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

I have added another answer to the issue you referenced, found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45358285/921904). Give this a shot, it is working for me.

P.S., you could skip the VCS step and instead store the needful file... anywhere... really. But the way I've written it when we upgrade our .NET Framework target I can simply check in the new version of the file and everything should continue to work.